# Oracle 12.1 JSON SQL command

Tags: sql, oracle

How to retrieve the below result from employee table HR schema

{"id":         100,
"manager":    "Steven King",
"numReports": 14,
"reports":    [101,102,114,120,121,122,123,124,145,146,147,148,149,201]}

{"id":         120,
"manager":    "Matthew Weiss",
"numReports": 8,
"reports":    [125,126,127,128,180,181,182,183]}

{"id":         121,
"manager":    "Adam Fripp",
"numReports": 8,
"reports":    [129,130,131,132,184,185,186,187]}

{"id":         122,
"manager":    "Payam Kaufling",
"numReports": 8,
"reports":    [133,134,135,136,188,189,190,191]}

{"id":         123,
"manager":    "Shanta Vollman",
"numReports": 8,
"reports":    [137,138,139,140,192,193,194,195]}

{"id":         124,
"manager":    "Kevin Mourgos",
"numReports": 8,
"reports":    [141,142,143,144,196,197,198,199]}

Comment: Even if this is not exactly the answer to your question; I suggest to follow this tutorial based on emp/dept table : https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_G8XGLBML23UDQNW25P6GZ3Q9V.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might to create a table with FIELD as CLOB or BLOB.
I recommend you the CLOB.

After to create the table you have to add a constraint as JSON...like:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_VDD_JSON(
    ID NUMBER,
    JSON_OBJ CLOB,
    CONSTRAINT TMP_VDD_JSON_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT JSON_CON CHECK (JSON_OBJ IS JSON)
);
```

When you have this table created you can do queries like:

```
SELECT j.JSON_OBJ.manager, ... , j.JSON_OBJ.reports FROM TMP_VDD_JSON j;
```

There are some conditions you must to follow.

1. You have to create the constraint and call all JSON FIELD with alias of table.
2. The fields into the CLOB as manager, reports, etc are keySensitive.
3. If you want to access to List of JSON, you have to learn about [*].

[OracleJsonDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6256)
Also if you have any specific question ask here and I will try to respond you.

Regards!